# Javascript need to pass variable using <a href> link with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I am using the code below for loading an external page into a lightbox. How could I pass from the href tag, a variable named 'page' to the javascript (line 1) containing the value of a page link = 'country.php'. I am wanting to use this script call several times without having to have additional javascript lines for each link.

```
<script>
$("a#selector").live("click", function(){$(".overlayInner").load("/country.php"); })
$("a#selector").live("click", function(){$(".overlayOuter").fadeIn(300); })
$("a#selector").live("click", function(){$(".overlayInner").fadeIn(500); })
$("a#selector").live("click", function(){$(".closepop").fadeIn(500); })
</script>


<a id="selector" href="#"><img src="/images/somegraphic.gif"></a>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to get the `href` attribute?

Comment: You'd just have to put your js code inside a function with a parameter, say, `function myFunc(url)`, use that url inside the `.load` as `.load(url)` and call your function passing the parameter you want. Really basic stuff, but you should be more specific.

Comment: No. I'm wanting to pass an additional variable to the javscript. Example: <a id="selector" page="country.php " href="#"><img src="/images/somegraphic.gif"></a>

Comment: Fabrício, thank you. I was making it more complicated than it was sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("a.selector").live("click", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    $(".overlayInner").load(url);
    return false;
});

<a class="selector" href="/country.php">Country</a>
<a class="selector" href="/pigs.php">Pigs</a>
```

If you want to get the inner text that says "Country", or an image you can do:

```
$("a.selector").live("click", function() {
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    var img = $(this).html(); // But what do you want to do with it?
    $(".overlayInner").load(url);
    return false;
});

<a class="selector" href="/country.php"><img src="img.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 5):

Couple points:

1. The jQuery [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method can be used to get any attribute, including the `href`, on any element.
2. Use the [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method with jQuery 1.7+ as [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated.
3. If you will have multiple `<a>` tags, you will need to refer to a `class` name instead of an `ID`. So you would use a "." instead of a "#". In your case, it would be `.selector` instead of `#selector`.
4. To reduce the number of statements inside the `click` function, you can combine the two `fadeIn()` functions that have the same time interval, `500`. Note below that you would use a "," to separate elements, in this case, `.overlayInner` and `.closepop`.
5. Since you are in a lightbox, the assumption is you will not want to migrate away to another page when you click the link. For this reason, you will need to use either `e.preventDefault` or `return false;` as the **last** statement inside the `click` function. The `e`, would be the [eventObject](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) passed into the [anonymous](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) `'click', 'a.selector', function(e)`.

Taken together, this is how your javascript could look.

```
var href=$("a.selector").attr('href', 'country.php');

$(document.body).on("click", "a.selector", function(){
    $(".overlayInner").load("'+href+'");
    $(".overlayOuter").fadeIn(300); 
    $(".overlayInner, .closepop").fadeIn(500); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: if you have `<a class="selector" href="/country.php"><img src="/images/somegraphic.gif"></a>` then you could also use javascript `this.href` to get the value of the `href` attribute: `.load("'+this.href+'");` (without declaring a `href` variable)

Comment: @JFK i vacillated on having `this` (ha!) as the 6th bulletpoint, hopefully that will be gleaned from the other answer.